# How can I keep Bootstrap & Angular2 projects separate?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm planning to keep my **Bootstrap** project (purely UI / view) separate from **Angular2** project (model processing, UI read / write & server communication).
How can I achieve this?

Comment: create two different app.modules RootModule & FeatureModule.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **CommonModule** as below,

   ```
   import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
   import { CommonModalComponent } from './modal.component';
   import { ModalDirective,ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
   @NgModule({
     imports:[ModalModule],
     declarations: [ CommonModalComponent ],
     exports:[CommonModalComponent]
   })
   export class CommonModule {}
   ```
2. As you can see, **CommonModalComponent** is a declaration in
   CommonModule, Create that component as below,

   ```
   import {Component,Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
   import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

   @Component({
     selector: 'common-modal', 
     template: `
      <div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
           <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideChildModal()">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <ng-content select=".modal-body"> </ng-content>
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
           <div class="pull-left">
             <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="hide()"> Cancel </button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
     `,
   })
   export class CommonModalComponent {
      @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal:ModalDirective;
      @Input() title?:string;
     constructor() {
     }
     show(){
       this.childModal.show();
     }
     hide(){
       this.childModal.hide();
     }
   }
   ```
3. Using the CommonModule and its components in the AppModule as below,

   ```
   import {Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
   import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import {CommonModule} from './common.module';
   import {CommonModalComponent} './modal.component';
   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
       <div>
         <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="childModal.show()">Open modal</button>
       <common-modal  #childModal [title]="'common modal'"> 
       </common-modal>
       </div>
     `,
   })
   export class App {
     @ViewChild('childComponent') childComponent:CommonModalComponent;
     name:string;
     constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
       this.name = 'Angular 2 Common Module with ModalComponent'
     }
   }

   @NgModule({
     imports: [ BrowserModule,CommonModule ],
     declarations: [ App ],
     bootstrap: [ App ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CT3JWI2BaPH1XAmupYLX?p=preview)